# Vincent - Pass a single array of objects to Data

Tags: python, vega

I am attempting to create a data array in [Vincent](http://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with a format similar to the one found in the [Vega tutorial](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Tutorial).

```
...
"data": [
  {
    "name": "table",
    "values": [
      {"x":"A", "y":28}, {"x":"B", "y":55}, {"x":"C", "y":43},
      {"x":"D", "y":91}, {"x":"E", "y":81}, {"x":"F", "y":53},
      {"x":"G", "y":19}, {"x":"H", "y":87}, {"x":"I", "y":52}
    ]
  }
],
...
```

However, I haven't figured out how to do it.  Using Data.from_iter() and Data.from_mult_iter() require that the data have explicit indices and column names.  I thought data.keypairs() looked promising, but that produced a dramatically different format as well.

Here are a few attempts thus far:

```
In [1]: coor = {'x': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'y': [28, 55, 43]}
In [2]: data = Data.keypairs(coor)
In [3]: print data.to_json()
{
  "name": "table",
  "values": [
    { "x": "x", "y": ["A","B","C"]},
    { "x": "y", "y": [28,55,43]}
  ]
}

In [4]: data = Data.from_iter(coor)
In [5]: print data.to_json()
{
  "name": "table", 
  "values": [
    {"col": "data", "idx": "x", "val": ["A", "B", "C"]}, 
    {"col": "data", "idx": "y", "val": [28, 55, 43]}
  ]
}

In [5]: coor = [{'x':'A', 'y':28}, {'x':'B', 'y':55}, {'x':'C', 'y':43}]
In [6]: data = Data.keypairs(coor)
In [7]: print data.to_json()
{
  "name": "table", 
  "values": [
    {"x": 0, "y": {"x": "A", "y": 28}}, 
    {"x": 1, "y": {"x": "B", "y": 55}},
    {"x": 2, "y": {"x": "C", "y": 43}}
  ]
}
In [8]: data = Data.from_iter(coor)
In [9]: print data.to_json()
{
  "name": "table", 
  "values": [
    {"col": "data", "idx": 0, "val": {"x": "A", "y": 28}}, 
    {"col": "data", "idx": 1, "val": {"x": "B", "y": 55}}, 
    {"col": "data", "idx": 2, "val": {"x": "C", "y": 43}}
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know how to produce the format above using Vincent?  What if I wanted objects with three key/value pairs, such as:

```
...
"data": [
  {
    "name": "table",
    "values": [
      {"x":"A", "y":28, "z":34}, {"x":"B", "y":55, "z":21}, ...
    ]
  }
],
...
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: well, you'd have to either get rid of the 'z' key because it looks like there's no 3d graph in vega. But I may have not look deep enough.

Comment: and you say you did not figure how to build a data array such as the example... but you're not showing what you actually tried. Can you give us some code?

Comment: Hi @zmo. Thanks for your advice. I updated the question to include some of my attempts thus far. It's also worth mentioning that there are plenty of reasons why I might wish to have three or more values per point. Bubble plots have three axes, but only two dimensions, for example. I might also wish to include extra information such as labels. With this updated information, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you plan on or are using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) already then this becomes very easy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Midnighter. I definitely believe you, but I'm not sure I know what you're going for. Would you be willing to elaborate a bit? It looks like Vincent has a to_pandas() method, but I'm struggling a bit to get it working. (I've barely used pandas.) Some example code would be tremendously helpful (maybe as an answer that I could then accept?). Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Going the `pandas` route is rewarding when working with `vincent`.

```python
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: coor = {'x': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'y': [28, 55, 43]}

In [3]: df = pandas.DataFrame(coor)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   x   y
0  A  28
1  B  55
2  C  43

[3 rows x 2 columns]

In [5]: import vincent

In [6]: bar = vincent.Bar(df)

In [7]: print bar.to_json()

{
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "type": "x"
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "type": "y"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {
          "col": "x",
          "idx": 0,
          "val": "A"
        },
        {
          "col": "y",
          "idx": 0,
          "val": 28
        },
        {
          "col": "x",
          "idx": 1,
          "val": "B"
        },
        {
          "col": "y",
          "idx": 1,
          "val": 55
        },
        {
          "col": "x",
          "idx": 2,
          "val": "C"
        },
        {
          "col": "y",
          "idx": 2,
          "val": 43
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "stats",
      "source": "table",
      "transform": [
        {
          "keys": [
            "data.idx"
          ],
          "type": "facet"
        },
        {
          "type": "stats",
          "value": "data.val"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "height": 500,
  "legends": [],
  "marks": [
    {
      "from": {
        "data": "table",
        "transform": [
          {
            "keys": [
              "data.col"
            ],
            "type": "facet"
          },
          {
            "height": "data.val",
            "point": "data.idx",
            "type": "stack"
          }
        ]
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {
                "field": "data.col",
                "scale": "color"
              },
              "width": {
                "band": true,
                "offset": -1,
                "scale": "x"
              },
              "x": {
                "field": "data.idx",
                "scale": "x"
              },
              "y": {
                "field": "y",
                "scale": "y"
              },
              "y2": {
                "field": "y2",
                "scale": "y"
              }
            }
          },
          "type": "rect"
        }
      ],
      "type": "group"
    }
  ],
  "padding": "auto",
  "scales": [
    {
      "domain": {
        "data": "table",
        "field": "data.idx"
      },
      "name": "x",
      "range": "width",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "zero": false
    },
    {
      "domain": {
        "data": "stats",
        "field": "sum"
      },
      "name": "y",
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "domain": {
        "data": "table",
        "field": "data.col"
      },
      "name": "color",
      "range": "category20",
      "type": "ordinal"
    }
  ],
  "width": 960
}
```

Adding further columns then becomes as easy as:

```
df["z"] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code, @Midnighter. The resulting JSON doesn't quite seem to work in the [Vega editor](https://trifacta.github.io/vega/editor/), but I do see how to create the data. However, this still doesn't quite match [the tutorial](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Tutorial). Note that in the tutorial, the data can be referenced like "data.x" and "data.y". The format your Vincent code produced doesn't allow for that kind of referencing. Is there any way to produce data formatted such that it can be referenced by field name using Vincent?  Thanks again for your example!

Comment: My bad, a DataFrame with multiple columns was a bad example for using a Bar plot. I will work on adjusting it. However, note that referencing does take place in the transforms and scales.

Comment: I see that you're able to reference "data.idx" and "data.val", but not "data.x", for example. Am I just missing something obvious? Seriously, thanks for taking the time to help me...

Comment: What is your intention of referencing them anyway? You can express almost everything in vincent and it will output correct JSON for you. Do you want to reference `data.x` just for the sake of following the tutorial or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: Honestly, this is my first time using either Vega or Vincent. I first designed a visualization in the Vega editor, and following success there, I attempted to recreate it using Vincent (since I'm adding this to an already extensive python project). The only discrepency in the Vega code Vincent produces is the format of the data. It ended up being a fairly intricate viz (I have decent D3 experience), and I was anxious to not revise everything when I could simply change the data format. (I was also just bothered that I couldn't figure it out!) I guess it's time to power through though, eh?

Comment: So basically you just want the data that you have in Python in a nice JSON format that you can plug into your vega + D3 Javascript? If it's a web app, why not give vega a url to load JSON from and then create exactly the format you're looking for?